# Pygame screen comes and goes

Tags: python, pygame

When I apply the code, the screen normally comes and goes, when it should give an error after it comes on, how do we fix this?

the allcode:

```
import os
import random

WIDTH = 750
HEIGHT = 600
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

#Imageları Yüklemek
BG = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "background_space.png"))


def main():
    run = True



    def draws():
        WIN.blit(BG, (0,0))


        while run:
            draws()



main()
```

Comment: this code would not yield the error you are complaining about as it is. Please, complete your example until you have a minimal self-contained code that can reproduce the error.

Comment: (I mean - that is how one writes nice questions. In your case, just add the statement `nonlocal run` at the beginning of your nested function, and you should be good)

Comment: `draws()` is never actually _called_, so this can't be the real code.

Comment: In the code, there was no error in the title, only the problem was that the screen came and went instead of being fixed, I couldn't solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`runs`  is not defined in the scope of the function `draws()`  . You should define it in the function you plan to use it in

Comment: actually - if all the code is this snippet, it is "defined enough" - Python supports nested scopes since 2001.  The thing is if there is an _assignment_ to `run` in the inner function, then it is compiled to be a local variable, and if it is read before, one gets a NameError. The code in the question is missing the important parts.

Comment: so how do i do this

Comment: You haven’t sent the code where you call the function draws(), nor have you sent the exact error! That’d be a good starting point